# How I can call BroadcastReceiver from intent service?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call `BroadcastReceiver` from intent service but it is never called:

```
public class IntentServiceTest extends IntentService {

    public IntentServiceTest() {
        super("IntentServiceTest");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(@Nullable Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Brodcast brodcast;
            brodcast = new Brodcast();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(brodcast, intentFilter);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
    public class Brodcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "BroadcastReceiver", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "100";
            String channelName = "My back";
            NotificationChannel channel;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
                channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
                channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                assert manager != null;
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

            ArrayList<String> arrayList;

            BluetoothDevice device;
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat;

            notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (!arrayList.contains(device.getName())) {
                    arrayList.add(device.getName());
                    if (arrayList.size() >= 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity3.class);
                i.putExtra("noti", NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
                Notification notification = n.setOngoing(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ss)
                        .setContentTitle(arrayList.size() + device.getName())
                        .addAction(R.drawable.as, "Action", pendingIntent)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText("App running"))
                        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                        .build();
                notificationManagerCompat.notify(1 , notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to call broadcast every 20 min; can anyone help me?

Comment: Your `IntentService` is registering a receiver... and then immediately getting destroyed, because an `IntentService` stops itself once `onHandleIntent()` completes. Since `IntentService` is deprecated, you should be doing something else. Note that if you need to do work every so often in the background, use `WorkManager`, not `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: what i can do to run it?

Comment: To run *what*? If you mean how to use `WorkManager`, that is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).